# resetting "Issue ID" in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, listview, counter, autonumber

I designed a site in share point. There is a column called  "Issue ID (linked to item)"   in ALL Issues view. I am using this column to list and identify the items which are created by employees. It increases by 1 as a new issue is created. Unfortunately, I have to reset this ID to 1 because during the test period I created and deleted blank issues. Although they were deleted, the share point increasing Issue ID from the last deleted issue (89).

Is there an easy way to do this? how can I reset this auto number? I need to reset this counter as soon as possible without any risk...

Do you kindly help me? I would be glad if you explain it in detail.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If your Issues list wasn't heavily customized and nor referenced by GUID in any custom code, the simplest and most supported option would be to recreate it with the same name after deletion as a customized template you could have saved *without* contents from list settings page before deleting or as a standard Issues list.